Poynting's theorem in dispersive media
I am reading Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (3rd ed) Section 6.8 on Poynting's Theorem in linear dispersive media with losses. From what I understand, in the last equation, the term $[-i\omega \epsilon(\omega)] \cdot E(\omega)e^{-i \omega t}$ in the integrand is coming from the Fourier expansion of the $\partial D/\partial t$ term.
My question then is: why do we take the complex conjugate of E when evaluating $E \cdot \partial D/\partial t$?
Thanks!


considering that the context is likely to be opticaI frequencies, I think Jackson is just ignoring the "double" or more precisely the sum frequency $\omega + \omega'$ terms because those would be very heavily attenuated and he only keeps the "low" that is difference frequency $\omega - \omega'$ terms, hence the complex conjugate.
